# Using Google Analytics for android widget

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-widget

I want to use Google Analytics for the first time.

I have a simple widget and when I click it a simple Activity opens up. Not that complicated. I put the following code in the onCreate-method of my Activity:

```
public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
public static Tracker tracker;


... from here in onCreate

if(analytics == null || tracker == null){
            analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

            tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-11111111-1");
            tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
            tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
            tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        }
```

Do I have to put the same code in my onUpdate-method of the AppWidgetProvider or is this already enough? Is a widget on the screen counted as an active user in Google Analytics and if so, does Google Analytics count 2 active users if they have the widget on screen and open the app or is Google smart enough to know that both (widget and app) are on the same device?